# How to detect the filename and url when a user try to attach to any email in browser using c#?

Tags: c#

I need to trace the filename and url if the file is being attached to any email in browser using c#. I can not find precise threads related to this. can some one please help?

Comment: Have you got any code that actually attaches the file?

Comment: Do you mean like a keylogger - you want to know when someone attaches a document to their private email using any browser on the machine?

Comment: @Shannon Holsinger thanks for your help. yes, if user is attach a file i need to log the url and the file name

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But no, it's not something you should ask for code for. What you are thinking of doing is very complicated and very illegal if you don't own the computer and inform the user of what you're doing. It's far easier to use a filter email address and have your users send to that with a bcc or as an auto-forwarder. There is almost no conceivable situation in which monitoring every attachment from every email account is warranted.

Comment: Thanks.. for security purpose i need to log the information and see what kind of files users attaching..

Comment: Much more easily done by looking at your email server's logs. Almost laughable invasion of privacy. Why not Google "How can I become a hacker?" and download some .exe files to learn about what you're trying to do. The company you're doing this for would get sued.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting this to your code:

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com/a.pdf";
NSArray *parts = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];
```